# React Hook. Cannot read property 'map' of nested list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a page in a create-react-app that is just used to read all items from a postgres query(just a simple join on id with two other tables).

The following returns from the query:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "highPriority":"foo",
        "medPriority":["foo", "bar"],
        "lowPriority":["foo", "bar"],
        "group":"123ABC",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "highPriority":"bar",
        "medPriority":["foo", "bar"],
        "lowPriority":["foo", "bar"],
        "group":"123ABC",
    },
    etc...
]
```

I am using react hooks so I set the state like so:

```
  const [priorities, setPriorities] = useState([{}]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const prioritiesArray = prioritiesService.getAll();
    setPriorities(prioritiesArray);

    
  }, [props])
```

And then attempt to map it like so: (class names are bootstrap)

```
return (
    <div>
      <h1>Priorities List</h1>
      {priorities.map(priorityObj => (
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{priorityObj.id}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{priorityObj.highPriority}</h6>
            {priorityObj.medPriority.map(medPriorityString => (
              <p class="card-text">{medPriorityString}</p>
            ))}
            {priorityObj.lowPriority.map(lowPriorityString => (
              <p class="card-text">{lowPriorityString}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

When I attempt to render page, i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

and it points to this line:

```
<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{priorityObj.highPriority}</h6>
```

right before the nested map.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are initializing the state with an array of objects, but with an empty object..

```js
const [priorities, setPriorities] = useState([{}]); 
// this makes React think there are childen in it,
// since length of array is now bigger than 0
```

React then tries to access this item and it's properties, and since they're all undefined you get this error. Try setting the state to something like:

```js
const [priorities, setPriorities] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const prioritiesArray = prioritiesService.getAll();
  setPriorities(prioritiesArray);
}, [props]);
```

Comment: I did this as per your answer and Marat's but I am now getting an error that priorities.map is not a function?

Comment: @KeenanHillerbrand what is your service returning?

Comment: It queries an API that returns the array of "priorities" in res.data

Comment: @KeenanHillerbrand most likely your service doesn't handle errors properly or returns something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your priorities with empty array, not array with empty object. This is your issue. Because then when you map your array, it gets your empty object as your array item, and then tries to call

```
.medPriority.map
```

And your empty object's "medPriority" property is undefined, and it tries to execute .medPriority.map, so undefined does not have map method :)
This should work:

```
  const [priorities, setPriorities] = useState([]);
```

Comment: This makes sense but I am now getting an error that priorities.map is not a function? Any thoughts?

Comment: It means that the result returned by your service is not array. But just in case you can put "?" sign before .  -   ?.map

Comment: I am sure it is an array. My service queries an API that returns the array of "priorities" in res.data. Also where to put the "?" sign?

Comment: priorities?.map